# If $A=A^{op}$ is $A^*=A$ in $A-mod$?

Tags: modules, algebras

Consider a finite-dimensional algebra $A$ over a field $k$. We have the dualization functor $*: Mod-A \to A-Mod$ given by

$$M^*=Hom_k(M,k).$$

This gives us a left $A$-module $A^*$. In general, it does not have to be isomorphic to $A$ as a left module.

But we may consider $A^*$ as a right module over the opposite algebra $A^{op}$. What if $A^{op}$ is isomorphic to $A$? Given a fixed isomorphism $A\cong A^{op}$, is there a way to give a canonical isomorphism $A^*\cong A$ as left $A$-modules (=right $A^{op}$-modules)? This seems like such a triviality, but I have been lost in all the isomorphisms and reversing multiplication orders for a few hours now.

Comment: No, e.g. $k[x]^* \cong k[[x]]$ as $k$-modules, even though $k[x]$ is commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this statement is true. The semi-canonical choices of $k$-linear morphisms $A \to A^*$ that I can come up with fail to be left $A$-module homomorphisms.

Nevertheless I will describe here my attempt. Let us choose a basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ for $A$ and let us simply spell out the condition for a $k$-linear morphism $\psi: A \to A^*$ to be a morphism of left $A$-modules. As a basis for $A^*$ we choose $\{\hat{e}_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where
\begin{aligned}
\hat{e_i}(e_j) := \begin{cases} 1 & i = j; \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
Let $\phi: A \to A^{\rm op}$ be the given involution of $A$, i.e. $\phi(1) = 1$ and $\phi(ab) = \phi(b)\phi(a)$. As you indicated, we then make $A^*$ into a left $A$-module by
\begin{aligned}
(a \cdot f)(b) := f(b\phi(a)).
\end{aligned}
Let's spell out what this is in coordinate. The multiplication $\mu: A \otimes A \to A$ can be written out in coordinates as
\begin{aligned}
e_i e_j = \mu(e_i \otimes e_j) = \sum_{k} \mu_{ijk} e_k.
\end{aligned}
Similarly the involution $\phi: A \to A^{\rm op}$ can be written in coordinates as
\begin{aligned}
\phi(e_i) = \sum_l \phi_{il} e_l.
\end{aligned}
The left $A$-action on $A^*$ thus becomes
\begin{aligned}
(e_i \cdot \hat{e}_j)(e_k) = \hat{e}_j(e_k\phi(e_i)) = \sum_m \phi_{im} \hat{e}_j(e_k \cdot e_m) = \sum_m \phi_{im} \mu_{kmj},
\end{aligned}
or in other words
\begin{aligned}
e_i \cdot \hat{e}_j = \sum_m \sum_k \phi_{im} \mu_{kmj} \hat{e}_k.
\end{aligned}
Now let us assume there is a $k$-linear isomorphism $\psi: A \to A^*$ given by $\psi(e_i) = \sum_j \psi_{ij} \hat{e}_j$ such that $\psi$ is an isomorphism of left $A$-modules. Then $\psi$ should satisfy the equation
\begin{aligned}
\psi(ab) = a \cdot \psi(b),
\end{aligned}
or in other words
\begin{aligned}
\psi(ab)(c) = \psi(b)(c\phi(a)).
\end{aligned}
Writing both sides out in coordinates, one obtains
\begin{aligned}
\psi(e_ie_j)(e_k) = \psi(\sum_{l}\mu_{ijl}e_l)(e_k) = \sum_l \mu_{ijl} \psi_{lk}
\end{aligned}
and
\begin{aligned}
\psi(e_j)(e_k\phi(e_i)) = \sum_m \phi_{im} \psi(e_j)(e_k e_m) = \sum_m \sum_n \phi_{im} \mu_{kmn} \psi(e_j)(e_n) = \sum_m \sum_n \phi_{im} \mu_{kmn} \psi_{jn}.
\end{aligned}
So all in all we need to find $\psi$ satisfying
\begin{aligned}
\sum_l \mu_{ijl} \psi_{lk} = \sum_m \sum_n \phi_{im} \mu_{kmn} \psi_{jn}.
\end{aligned}
We see that taking $\psi_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ could work whenever we have the identity
\begin{aligned}
\mu_{ijk} = \sum_m \phi_{im} \mu_{kmj},
\end{aligned}
which seems like a very strange condition to me. Another attempt could be taking $\psi_{ij} = \phi_{ij}$, which probably also won't work in general since the condition $\phi(ab) = \phi(b)\phi(a)$ translates into the condition that
\begin{aligned}
\sum_l \mu_{ijl} \phi_{lk} = \sum_m \sum_n \phi_{jn} \phi_{im} \mu_{nmk};
\end{aligned}
the above condition would thus for example be satisfied if $\mu_{nmk} = \mu_{kmn}$ were to hold, which again seems like a strange condition.

I wouldn't be surprised at this point when someone comes up with an explicit counterexample.

Comment: Thank you! Now I also think that there must be a counterexample. In my case something more subtle was involved in the existence of the isomorphism $A\cong A^*$.